# Store javascript codes in velocity vm template file and included in the page

Tags: javascript, velocity

I have javascript code that uses velocity context and rundata objects, I have to have it to be included in a VM template. Is there a way for me to separate it into standalone file, say, screen-js.vm, and included in the GlobalMacros.vm file, like:

and screen-js.vm looks like:

```
    $data.setLayoutTemplate("/NoNavigationJs.vm") ##this for not creating any header

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
         //javascript code ...

    }
</script>
```

But this doesn't work, here is the page source, with 2 empty lines in the begining:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
...
}
</script>
```

What I did wrong here? Thanks!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
#parse("path/to/vm file") will do.